# How do we merge matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I have 3 matrices of exactly the same size. I would like to merge them into one matrix of the same size.

```
A <- array(0,c(10,20))
```

For Matrix A;

```
      [1] [2] [3] .. [20]
 [1]  A11 A12 A13 .. A120 
 [2]
  ..
[10]
```

For Matrix B;

```
      [1] [2] [3] .. [20]
 [1]  B11 B12 B13 .. B120 
 [2]
  ..
[10]
```

For Matrix C;

```
      [1] [2] [3] .. [20]
 [1]  C11 C12 C13 .. C120 
 [2]
  ..
[10]
```

I am not sure how to do it but I would like the output to be like this:-

Output Matrix D;

```
                    [1]               [2]   ..            [20]
 [1]      (A11,B11,C11)     (A12,B12,C12)  .. (A120,B120,C120) 
 [2]
  ..
[10]   (A101,B101,C101)  (A102,B102,C102)
```

I have tried using the `cbind` command but it combines all of the three matrices and the row become too long. I want the same size just like the single matrix (10x20).

Comment: What do you plan to do afterwards? Your question is a bit unclear as is your intention. `array` will be useful to construct a 3D array.

Comment: i just want to summarize the result obtained in a single matrix.

Comment: Ok, summarise how - `mean`? `sum`? `product`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use an `array`, eg:

```
x <- matrix(1:9,3)
y <- matrix(10:18,3)
z <- matrix(19:27,3)

arr <- array(c(x,y,z), dim=c(dim(x),3))
arr[1,1,]
[1]  1 10 19
```

If you want to view it as a single "matrix" you can use `apply` and `paste`:

```
apply(arr,1:2,paste,collapse=",")
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] "1,10,19" "4,13,22" "7,16,25"
[2,] "2,11,20" "5,14,23" "8,17,26"
[3,] "3,12,21" "6,15,24" "9,18,27"
```

Comment: And `apply` to summarise. `apply( arr , 1:2 , mean )`